# Is it possible to have two templates in an article hirearchy?

Tags: theme-development

I'm creating a custom theme.

The articles are organized so that related articles form a hirearchy of specificity. More general articles (e.g. articles about automobiles) are at the top level and more specific articles (e.g. articles about Honda Civics) are at lower levels.

This hirearchy is reflected in the breadcrumbs at the top of the page and in a topic-navigation menu on the left side of each article (see image).

Not every article page will use the same template. I'll need at least two types of page templates used in the hirearchies. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, sure it's possible. But what are those articles - regular posts (type `post`), Pages (type `page`), CPT, or a combination of that? How would you determine which articles use what template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create multiple templates for a custom post. Simply create a new template page and add the following code in the template header:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Article type 1
 * Template Post Type: post, page
 */
get_header(); 
?>
```